# Node.js - update server page

Tags: javascript, node.js

After create the http server and listen to it:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.write("<!DOCTYPE "html">");
  response.write("<html>");
  response.write("<head>");
  response.write("<title>Hello World</title>");
  response.write("</head>");
  response.write("<body>");
  response.write("Hello World!");
  response.write("</body>");
  response.write("</html>");
  response.end();
});

server.listen(1337);
```

now I want to update the page but don't want to exit() the server. How can I do it?

Comment: how do you plan to update this page? via client-side request? you can also use `request` to make an external `POST` or `GET` and change the content

Comment: `response.write()` is good for Hello World but in real application you want to load external html file

Answer (score 0):

Use **Nodemon**, it is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source files and automatically restart your server.

Steps:

- Install nodemon globally `npm install nodemon -g`
- Run the server `nodemon app.js`

This way you do not have to exit the server everytime you update the page/server logic.

Answer (score 0):

As @**Pavol Pitonak** suggested, you should use multiple files, one for node server boot, second for index page, so when you edit your `index.html` file - server doesn't need restart.

`server.js` file

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){

    // get path to file we gonna send
    var indexFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');

    // read file contents
    fs.readFile(indexFilePath, function(err, contents){
        if(err){
            // for debugging
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            // send file content
            res.end(contents);
        }
    });
});

server.listen(1337);
```

`index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    Hello world
  </body>
</html>
```